# getting errors when use OpenGL with python on macos

Tags: python, macos, opengl

I'm trying to play around with OpenGl and python on macos. And when I run the code from tutorial I get errors:

> GLUT Warning: The following is a new check for GLUT 3.0; update your
>   code.
>
> GLUT Fatal Error: redisplay needed for window 1, but no display
>   callback.

The code I try to run:

```
from OpenGL.GL import * 
from OpenGL.GLU import * 
from OpenGL.GLUT import * 

glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB) 
glutInitWindowSize(300, 300)
glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50)
glutInit(sys.argv)
glutCreateWindow(b"Happy New Year!")
glutMainLoop()
```

[There's already a question about this problem on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302800/glut-warning-and-glut-fatal-error-in-a-python-code-that-runs-in-another-machine), but a clear answer wasn't given to this question. As far as I understand, I should add

`glutDisplayFunc(glutCreateWindow)` 
right before

```
glutMainLoop()
```

But if I do so, I get another error:

> TypeError: this function takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`glutMainLoop`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node14.html) runns the event processing loop. When doing this, the callback function which is set by [`glutDisplayFunc`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node46.html) is called. You have to implement and set this function:

e.g.

```py
def display:
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    # do the drawing
    # .....

    glutSwapBuffers()
    glutPostRedisplay()

glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB) 
glutInitWindowSize(300, 300)
glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50)
glutInit(sys.argv)
glutCreateWindow(b"Happy New Year!")

glutDisplayFunc(display)
glutMainLoop()
```

Note, [`glutPostRedisplay`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node20.html) marks the current window as needing to be redisplayed, this causes the window to be redisplayed continuously. [`glutSwapBuffers`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node21.html) swaps the buffers of the current window, this means it makes the drawing "visible" on the viewport.